# NormalEstimation for 2D point cloud

Tags: pcl, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is there a way to estimate normals  for a 2D point cloud (XY plane & *Unorganized
point cloud*) .  To give a small background the point cloud is formed from
Laser scan messages using [laser_geometry](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_geometry) package.

As per the PCL documentation, it try to fit a plane and estimate the normal
but in my case all the points are present in a plane. So is there a way to
find the normal lying the same 2D plane. Some thing like fitting a line and
finding the norm.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284090/normalestimation-for-2d-point-cloud/) by [BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28829/bhanukiran.chaluvadi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2018-03-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will probably have to do the local model estimation manually because PCL doesn't have a `PointXY` type. It should be quite straightforward to do a least-squares line fit once you've identified the neighborhood of each point.

Someone else may be able to comment on how difficult it would be to make your own `PointXY` type and plug into the PCL machinery for doing normal estimation.

---

Originally posted by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) with karma: 971 on 2018-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tuandl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28760/tuandl/) on 2018-03-01**:
I would like to suggest a hack by assigning a Z value to your point cloud. Z may be arbitrary or it may be the actual distance from where you place your laser scan to the ground. I know this is not the best solution but at least you could bypass writing your own PointXY type.

**Comment by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on 2018-03-01**:
But I think the issue is that he/she wants the 2D normals, pointing out from say a blob obstacle (correct me if I'm mistaken). If the points become 3D I'm not aware of any (built-in) method of doing a local model estimation in a single plane.

**Comment by [BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28829/bhanukiran.chaluvadi/) on 2018-03-02**:
PCL has a datatype pcl::pointXY. Currently, I am getting all the norms pointing in z - direction (0, 0, 1). Obviously the fitted plane is XY and the norm is in Z-direction. I am looking for norm that look some thing like  (x, y, 0) in the plane XY.

**Comment by [BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28829/bhanukiran.chaluvadi/) on 2018-03-04**:
@tuandi  I still don't understand your solution. By assigning the random z value will make the points 3 Dimensional. But when it comes to plane fitting for the points I am not sure how its going to work out and give a correct norm.

**Comment by [tuandl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28760/tuandl/) on 2018-03-04**:
Hi, I might misuderstand your question. My idea is that if you have a normal 3D poincloud then you can you SACSegmentation to estimate your plane. Having the plane coefficients then it is simple to get the norm vector. Isn’t it what you need?